# Issue appending dictionaries to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to loop through a text file block by block (5 blocks) to capture the data in key value pairs (using dictionaries). However, only the last block gets appended to the list of dictionaries 5 times

I've tried moving the dictionary initialization inside the loop but it  doesn't work

```
jsonData = list()
blockIdentifier = set(chr(10))
filename = "test.txt"
counter = 0
lineId = None
currentJson = {}

for line in open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8"):
    '''print(line)
    for ochar in line:
        print(str(ochar)+" - "+str(ord(ochar))),
    break'''
    print(line)
    if set(line).issubset(blockIdentifier):
        jsonData.append(currentJson)
        currentJson.clear()
        counter += 1
    else:
        if ':' in line:
            line = line.strip()
            x = line.split(':', 1)
            currentJson[x[0]] = x[1]
            lineId = x[0]
        elif line.startswith('/s/s/s'):
            line = line.strip()
            currentJson[lineId] += line
        else:
            pass
print(jsonData)
```

Text File:

```
inetnum:        193.194.64.0 - 193.194.95.255
netname:        DZ-ARN-970407
descr:          PROVIDER
descr:          Algerian Academic Research Network
country:        DZ
org:            ORG-AARN1-AFRINIC
admin-c:        EG71
tech-c:         EG71
status:         ALLOCATED PA
remarks:        data has been transferred from RIPE Whois Database 20050221
notify:         ***@arn.dz
notify:         ***@arn.dz
mnt-by:         AFRINIC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      AS16214-MNT
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19970407
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19981020
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19990104
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20000309
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20000428
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20020313
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20050205
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20121211
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20180212
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20180228
source:         AFRINIC

inetnum:        193.95.0.0 - 193.95.127.255
netname:        TN-ATI-20010402
descr:          Agence Tunisienne Internet - ATI
descr:          Provider Local Registry
country:        TN
org:            ORG-ATIA2-AFRINIC
admin-c:        JF13-AFRINIC
tech-c:         TG12-AFRINIC
status:         ALLOCATED PA
remarks:        Previously allocated to eu.eunet
remarks:        data has been transferred from RIPE Whois Database 20050221
notify:         ***@ati.tn
notify:         ***@ati.tn
notify:         ***@ati.tn
notify:         ***@ati.tn
mnt-by:         AFRINIC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      ATI-MNT
mnt-domains:    ATI-MNT
changed:        ***@EU.net 19960208
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19960513
changed:        ***@EU.net 19990201
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19990202
changed:        ***@EU.net 19990204
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20000420
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20040226
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20050205
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20050218
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20130611
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20161208
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20170214
source:         AFRINIC

inetnum:        194.204.192.0 - 194.204.255.255
netname:        ONPT
descr:          Office National des Postes et Telecommunications
descr:          aka Maroc Telecom
country:        MA
admin-c:        SM13-AFRINIC
tech-c:         SM13-AFRINIC
org:            ORG-ONdP1-AFRINIC
status:         ALLOCATED PA
mnt-by:         AFRINIC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      ONPT-MNT
notify:         ***@iam.net.ma
notify:         ***@menara.ma
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19960111
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19980203
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19990422
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20030106
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20050205
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20060828
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20100118
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20100208
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20100609
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20110602
source:         AFRINIC

inetnum:        194.79.96.0 - 194.79.127.255
netname:        EG-IE-951129
descr:          Internet Egypt Co.
country:        EG
org:            ORG-NO1-AFRINIC
admin-c:        MM2370-AFRINIC
admin-c:        IAM13-AFRINIC
tech-c:         MM2370-AFRINIC
tech-c:         IAM13-AFRINIC
status:         ALLOCATED PA
notify:         ***@etisalat.com
mnt-by:         AFRINIC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      AS5536-MNT
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19951129
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19980916
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20020215
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20020220
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20050205
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20111021
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20180215
source:         AFRINIC

inetnum:        195.202.64.0 - 195.202.95.255
netname:        MTN-Business
descr:          MTN Business
country:        KE
admin-c:        NA34-AFRINIC
tech-c:         NA34-AFRINIC
org:            ORG-NOIS1-AFRINIC
status:         ALLOCATED PA
mnt-by:         AFRINIC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      AS9129-MNT
remarks:        data has been transferred from RIPE Whois Database 20050221
notify:         ***@mtnbusiness.co.ke
notify:         ***@mtnbusiness.co.ke
changed:        ***@ripe.net 19970228
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20020312
changed:        ***@ripe.net 20020315
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20050205
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20120731
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20120801
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20140801
source:         AFRINIC

inetnum:        195.24.192.0 - 195.24.223.255
netname:        CM-CAMTEL-970403
descr:          Data communication and international
descr:          telecommunication of Cameroon
country:        CM
org:            ORG-IA6-AFRINIC
admin-c:        NED2-AFRINIC
tech-c:         JN1000-AFRINIC
tech-c:         BLV1-AFRINIC
tech-c:         TAJJ1-AFRINIC
status:         ALLOCATED PA
notify:         ***@camnet.cm
notify:         ***@camnet.cm
notify:         ***@camnet.cm
notify:         ***@yahoo.com
mnt-by:         AFRINIC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      CAMTEL-MNT
mnt-routes:     CAMTEL-MNT
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20060601
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20060602
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20121213
changed:        ***@afrinic.net 20140918
source:         AFRINIC
```

I want to get the text in key-value pairs preferably in a list of dictionaries grouped by block

Comment: `line.strip()` alone does nothing if you don't assign it back to `line`

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't use `json.loads` from https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html ? Unless you are not allowed to (an exercise that bans `json.loads`) you should use the json package

Comment: The text file is not in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we ignore the concept of grouping by blocks and try to get every valid line as a dictionary. We'll store this in a variable `s`.

```
filename = 'data.txt'
s = [ { x.split(':')[0] : x.split(':')[1].strip() } for x in open(filename).read().split('\n') if ':' in x ]
```

This will give an output like this:

```
[{'inetnum': '193.194.64.0 - 193.194.95.255'}, {'netname': 'DZ-ARN-970407'}, {'descr': 'PROVIDER'}, {'descr': 'Algerian Academic Research Network'}, {'country': 'DZ'}, {'org': 'ORG-AARN1-AFRINIC'}, {'admin-c': 'EG71'}, {'tech-c': 'EG71'}, {'status': 'ALLOCATED PA'}, {'remarks': 'data has been transferred from RIPE Whois Database 20050221'}, {'notify': '***@arn.dz'}, {'notify': '***@arn.dz'}, {'mnt-by': 'AFRINIC-HM-MNT'}, {'mnt-lower': 'AS16214-MNT'}, {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19970407'}, {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19981020'}, {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19990104'}, {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20000309'}, {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20000428'}, {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20020313'}, {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20050205'}, {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20121211'}, {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20180212'}, {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20180228'}, {'source': 'AFRINIC'}, {'inetnum': '193.95.0.0 - 193.95.127.255'}, ... ]
```

Now we find out where the separators ( that is, lines without ":" ) are placed. We'll store this in a variable `t`.

```
t = ''.join([ "1" if ':' in x else "0" for x in open(filename).read().split('\n')]).strip("0")
```

This will give a string where "1" stands for a normal line and "0" stands for a separator.

```
'111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111101111111111111111111110111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111'
```

Next we add "0" separators to our list of dictionaries according to the pattern stored in `t`. We'll call this `w`.

```
w = [ s.pop(0) if int(x) else "0" for x in t ]
```

Now we have something like this:

```
[  ... {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20170214'}, {'source': 'AFRINIC'}, '0', {'inetnum': '194.204.192.0 - 194.204.255.255'}, {'netname': 'ONPT'}, {'descr': 'Office National des Postes et Telecommunications'}, {'descr': 'aka Maroc Telecom'}, {'country': 'MA'}, ... ]
```

So we can find the indices for the "0" strings and use them to split this list into a list of lists. We'll also use a filter to remove the "0" separator from the result.

```
indices = [ i for (i,x) in enumerate(w) if x == '0' ]
right = indices + [len(w)]
left = [0] + indices
result = [ list(filter(lambda x: x != "0", w[start:end])) for (start,end) in zip(left,right)]
```

So now `result` has our desired output, as we can see by running `import pprint; pprint.PrettyPrinter().pprint(result)` :

```
[[{'inetnum': '193.194.64.0 - 193.194.95.255'},
  {'netname': 'DZ-ARN-970407'},
  {'descr': 'PROVIDER'},
  {'descr': 'Algerian Academic Research Network'},
  {'country': 'DZ'},
  {'org': 'ORG-AARN1-AFRINIC'},
  {'admin-c': 'EG71'},
  {'tech-c': 'EG71'},
  {'status': 'ALLOCATED PA'},
  {'remarks': 'data has been transferred from RIPE Whois Database 20050221'},
  {'notify': '***@arn.dz'},
  {'notify': '***@arn.dz'},
  {'mnt-by': 'AFRINIC-HM-MNT'},
  {'mnt-lower': 'AS16214-MNT'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19970407'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19981020'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19990104'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20000309'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20000428'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20020313'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20050205'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20121211'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20180212'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20180228'},
  {'source': 'AFRINIC'}],
 [{'inetnum': '193.95.0.0 - 193.95.127.255'},
  {'netname': 'TN-ATI-20010402'},
  {'descr': 'Agence Tunisienne Internet - ATI'},
  {'descr': 'Provider Local Registry'},
  {'country': 'TN'},
  {'org': 'ORG-ATIA2-AFRINIC'},
  {'admin-c': 'JF13-AFRINIC'},
  {'tech-c': 'TG12-AFRINIC'},
  {'status': 'ALLOCATED PA'},
  {'remarks': 'Previously allocated to eu.eunet'},
  {'remarks': 'data has been transferred from RIPE Whois Database 20050221'},
  {'notify': '***@ati.tn'},
  {'notify': '***@ati.tn'},
  {'notify': '***@ati.tn'},
  {'notify': '***@ati.tn'},
  {'mnt-by': 'AFRINIC-HM-MNT'},
  {'mnt-lower': 'ATI-MNT'},
  {'mnt-domains': 'ATI-MNT'},
  {'changed': '***@EU.net 19960208'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19960513'},
  {'changed': '***@EU.net 19990201'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19990202'},
  {'changed': '***@EU.net 19990204'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20000420'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20040226'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20050205'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20050218'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20130611'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20161208'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20170214'},
  {'source': 'AFRINIC'}],
 [{'inetnum': '194.204.192.0 - 194.204.255.255'},
  {'netname': 'ONPT'},
  {'descr': 'Office National des Postes et Telecommunications'},
  {'descr': 'aka Maroc Telecom'},
  {'country': 'MA'},
  {'admin-c': 'SM13-AFRINIC'},
  {'tech-c': 'SM13-AFRINIC'},
  {'org': 'ORG-ONdP1-AFRINIC'},
  {'status': 'ALLOCATED PA'},
  {'mnt-by': 'AFRINIC-HM-MNT'},
  {'mnt-lower': 'ONPT-MNT'},
  {'notify': '***@iam.net.ma'},
  {'notify': '***@menara.ma'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19960111'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19980203'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19990422'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20030106'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20050205'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20060828'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20100118'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20100208'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20100609'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20110602'},
  {'source': 'AFRINIC'}],
 [{'inetnum': '194.79.96.0 - 194.79.127.255'},
  {'netname': 'EG-IE-951129'},
  {'descr': 'Internet Egypt Co.'},
  {'country': 'EG'},
  {'org': 'ORG-NO1-AFRINIC'},
  {'admin-c': 'MM2370-AFRINIC'},
  {'admin-c': 'IAM13-AFRINIC'},
  {'tech-c': 'MM2370-AFRINIC'},
  {'tech-c': 'IAM13-AFRINIC'},
  {'status': 'ALLOCATED PA'},
  {'notify': '***@etisalat.com'},
  {'mnt-by': 'AFRINIC-HM-MNT'},
  {'mnt-lower': 'AS5536-MNT'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19951129'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19980916'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20020215'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20020220'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20050205'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20111021'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20180215'},
  {'source': 'AFRINIC'}],
 [{'inetnum': '195.202.64.0 - 195.202.95.255'},
  {'netname': 'MTN-Business'},
  {'descr': 'MTN Business'},
  {'country': 'KE'},
  {'admin-c': 'NA34-AFRINIC'},
  {'tech-c': 'NA34-AFRINIC'},
  {'org': 'ORG-NOIS1-AFRINIC'},
  {'status': 'ALLOCATED PA'},
  {'mnt-by': 'AFRINIC-HM-MNT'},
  {'mnt-lower': 'AS9129-MNT'},
  {'remarks': 'data has been transferred from RIPE Whois Database 20050221'},
  {'notify': '***@mtnbusiness.co.ke'},
  {'notify': '***@mtnbusiness.co.ke'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 19970228'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20020312'},
  {'changed': '***@ripe.net 20020315'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20050205'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20120731'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20120801'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20140801'},
  {'source': 'AFRINIC'}],
 [{'inetnum': '195.24.192.0 - 195.24.223.255'},
  {'netname': 'CM-CAMTEL-970403'},
  {'descr': 'Data communication and international'},
  {'descr': 'telecommunication of Cameroon'},
  {'country': 'CM'},
  {'org': 'ORG-IA6-AFRINIC'},
  {'admin-c': 'NED2-AFRINIC'},
  {'tech-c': 'JN1000-AFRINIC'},
  {'tech-c': 'BLV1-AFRINIC'},
  {'tech-c': 'TAJJ1-AFRINIC'},
  {'status': 'ALLOCATED PA'},
  {'notify': '***@camnet.cm'},
  {'notify': '***@camnet.cm'},
  {'notify': '***@camnet.cm'},
  {'notify': '***@yahoo.com'},
  {'mnt-by': 'AFRINIC-HM-MNT'},
  {'mnt-lower': 'CAMTEL-MNT'},
  {'mnt-routes': 'CAMTEL-MNT'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20060601'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20060602'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20121213'},
  {'changed': '***@afrinic.net 20140918'},
  {'source': 'AFRINIC'}]]
```

So here's all the code we have written:

```
filename = 'data.txt'
s = [ { x.split(':')[0] : x.split(':')[1].strip() } \
     for x in open(filename).read().split('\n') if ':' in x ]
t = ''.join([ "1" if ':' in x else "0" \
             for x in open(filename).read().split('\n')]).strip("0")
w = [ s.pop(0) if int(x) else "0" \
     for x in t ]
indices = [ i for (i,x) in enumerate(w) if x == '0' ]
right = indices + [len(w)]
left = [0] + indices
result = [ list(filter(lambda x: x != "0", w[start:end]))  \
          for (start,end) in zip(left,right)]
```